# Continuable fractions

Tags: number-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be positive integers such that the first few digits of the fractions
$\dfrac{29}{{\color{red}{70}}},\ \dfrac{{\color{red}{70}}}{{\color{blue}{169}}},\ \dfrac{{\color{blue}{169}}}{{\color{green}{408}}},\ \dfrac{{\color{green}{408}}}{{\color{brown}{X}}},\ \dfrac {{\color{brown}{X}}}{{\color{grey}{Y}}} $
are all equal to $0.4142$. What is ${{\color{brown}{X}}}+{{\color{grey}{Y}}}?$

Note: The fractions are not equal.

Comment: by cross-multiplying, $169X \approx 408^2$ and $408Y \approx X^2$

Comment: This sequence emerges by subtracting $1$ from the convergents of the continued fraction of $\sqrt{2}$, if we begin with the convergent $\frac{99}{70}$

Comment: Pretty suspicious behavior. All 5 of your questions seemed to be answered by you yourself (Bailey Oakley), and you yourself have accepted 4 of the questions.

Comment: You do realize that systematically voting in favor of class mate **is** against the rules here. And I'm the Sheriff. This looks bad. A round of detective work coming up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A useful trick for approximating the fractional part of $\sqrt{2}$ is the following sequence
$\frac{p}{q}\implies \frac{q}{p+2q}$
Clearly, the sequence in question follows this sequence as shown below
$\frac{29}{70} \implies \frac{70}{29 + (2)(70)} = \frac{70}{169} \implies \frac{169}{70 + (2)(169)} = \frac{169}{408} $
Therefore, the sequence containing $X$ and $Y$ is as follows
$\frac{169}{408}, \frac{408}{985}, \frac{985}{2378}$

Thus, $X + Y = 985 + 2378 = \boxed{3363}$

Comment: Pretty suspicious behavior. All 5 of the Strategy Gamer's questions seemed to be answered by you, and you have been accepted for 4 of them.

Comment: He emails me a lot about Math questions because am tutoring him

Comment: You are a tutor for another person at Dartmouth college?

Comment: No, he is just my neighbor that goes to another college. He just wants a tutor because of how badly he is doing in class

Comment: You can get suspended for these actions in this website.

Comment: He is the one accepting them and am just answering them because he emails me to answer it

Comment: I'm just saying this because the website will think you are using "sockpuppets" (bots). Please end the conversation here. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for accepting her answer, making her look like she is using sockpuppets. The only reson why I ask her because she is the only tutor I can find that will work for free. @idk please understand that she is not a bad person, she just wants to help me with Math. Hopw it is clear now

Comment: @TheStrategyGamer I am not implying that she is "a bad person", but just telling you about how the site functions.

Comment: Ok sorry I understand that this is not an acceptable behavior on this site, I will try to minimize this kind of behavior. Thank you for the talk and have a nice day :)

Comment: Independent of any discussion of sock-puppeting, this is not a good answer; it explains what the sequence is, but doesn't really provide any insight into the problem, an explanation of _where_ the solution comes from, or an explanation as to why the solution is unique.

Answer (score 1):

There is a relatively trivial solution to this problem: we know that $\frac{408}X\approx .4142$; this means that $X\approx \frac{408}{.4142}=985.0313\ldots$ etc.  Now, any $X$ larger than this will lead to a ratio $\frac{408}X$ that's less than $.4142$ and thus can't start with those digits. What's more, by explicit calculation, $\frac{408}{984}=.4146\ldots$ is clearly too large; thus $985$ is the only possible value for $X$. Once $X$ has been found this way, $Y$ can be computed using exactly the same method.